# overlay/lightbox needed to display internal html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a overlay to display a internal html page. I started with dynamic DHTML modalbox but the code was outdated for HTML5 browsers(didn't show properly for MS Edge). I found something called LightBox, but it only look like it display images.

Modal Window: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/dhtmlmodal.htm

LightBox: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/super-simple-lightbox-with-css-and-jquery--webdesign-3528

All I want is a jquery overlay page that shows internal webpages. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to use a library or write it by yourself?

Comment: Library aka something I can simply apply to my website. It's just a basic website that I am trying to add overlay to instead of opening to new page

Comment: Here is a list of lightbox libraries: https://codegeekz.com/responsive-jquery-lightbox-libraries/ However, these are mostly for images. This one can also display a website in it: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: If you plan to base your website on a style framework like Bootstrap, you have all this functionality already included (Modal). Here is a link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo

Comment: Yes I currently using twitter bootstrap

Comment: If you are using twitter bootstrap, you should take a look at the link I provided above. Everything is already in there.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

in your style section add:

```
        .overlay-background {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height:100%;
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            z-index: 1000; /* high z-index */
            background: #000; /* fallback */
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }

        .overlay-content 
        {
            display: block;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 1%;
            width: 40%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 15%;
            left: 50%;
            margin: 0 0 0 -20%;
            cursor: default;
            z-index: 10001;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        }
```

in your HTML section add but remember to change the URL to whatever page you want shown:

```
    <div class="overlay-content">
       <object type="text/html" data="https://www.google.com" style="width: 50%; height: 50%;"></object>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-background">
    </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.. I create a fiddle to test https://jsfiddle.net/benjones337/0L3s523p/#&togetherjs=ytS774Dvny